# Output a dictionary based on inputs from another dictionary and two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and two lists and would like to output another dictionary that contains the individual list as the title and sum of the list contents as the values however, I have no clue as to how I could do this.

```
results = {'Apple':'14.0', 'Banana':'12.0', 'Orange':'2.0', 'Pineapple':'9.0'}

ListA = ['Apple','Pineapple']
ListB = ['Banana','Orange']
```

Output:

```
dicttotal = {'ListA':'23.0', 'ListB':'14.0'}
```

Edit: I have decided to use pandas to work with the above data as I find that the simplicity of pandas is more suited for my level of understanding. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: you could use integeral values to make it easier.

Comment: How shall the output look like if someone does `ListA = ['Apple','Pineapple']; ListB = ListA; ListC = ['Banana','Orange']`?

Comment: If you have no clue, perhaps you are looking for a basic tutorial rather than a free code handout?

Comment: @timgeb what is difficult about resolving that scenario

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I was trying to point out that a value can have many names (additionally, names refer to values unidirectionally), so what would be the appropriate key for the `['Apple','Pineapple']` list in the desired output-dict?

Comment: @timgeb would it not be `{'ListA': '23.0', 'ListB': '23.0', 'ListC': '14.0'}`, they are equal after all, two keys with same values

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I don't know, OP never answered the question.

Comment: @timgeb well so far the format is `{'list_name': 'sum'}`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I think you are missing the point. You still have to hardcode the dict keys, which OP is probably not aware of. You cannot get from a value to its name (or many names).

Comment: @timgeb I'm aware I mentioned that in my solution provided, therefore OP naming scheme is a manual one, but the format of the output is still clear

Comment: @vash_the_stampede maye. We will know once OP clarifies or accepts an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python you can use list comprehensions to make this easy to read:

```
items_for_a = [float(v) for i, v in results.items() if i in ListA]
total_a = sum(items_for_a)
```

the `dicttotal` you want to print is strange, though. I don't think you want to print variable names as dictionary keys.

in python2 you should use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`

Comment: I think having the variable names as dictionary keys is exactly what OP wants. You have the chance to explain why they should not want this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use fllowing code get ListA's sum. The same way for ListB. Just try it yourself

```
dicttotal = {}
ListASum = 0.0
ListBSum = 0.0
for item in ListA:
    if item in results:
        ListASum += float(results[item])
dicttotal['ListA'] = ListASum
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce and dictionary comprehension to create dictionary with an initial value, followed by updating a single value. Had key names not been variable names maybe could have done dict comprehension for both.

```
from functools import reduce
d_total = {'ListA': str(reduce(lambda x, y: float(results[x]) + float(results[y]), lista))}
d_total['ListB'] = str(reduce(lambda x, y: float(results[x]) + float(results[y]), listb))
```

> ```
> {'ListA': '23.0', 'ListB': '14.0'}
> ```

*Note: PEP-8 snake_case for naming*

Answer (score 0):

One-liner, using the (ugly) `eval()` function, but as Eduard said, it's better not to use variable names as keys :

```
{list_name: str(sum([float(results[item]) for item in eval(list_name)])) for list_name in ['ListA', 'ListB']}
```